# Logical solution for using 2 theories calculating pi, to converge to pi

Tags: python, logic

This is a task for a programming course. We need to approximate π using 2 different functions. 1 uses Gregory-Leibniz theory, the other Madhava of Sangamagrama's . Both of these aren't any problem, but the third function is giving me some trouble. :

Examine which of both sequences converges the fastest. Use this sequence to write a function approach_pi. This function should allow to determine an approached value of **π** , that is precise to **n** decimals. The value **n** should be given as an argument of the function. To determine the accuracy of the approach, you should check whether the difference between two consecutive **terms** in the sequence is smaller than 10^-n-1. When the difference between the **(i-1)th** and the **i-th** term becomes smaller than 10^-n-1, the i-th partial sum forms an approach of π to **(n)** decimals precisely. The function should give the tuple **(i, p)** as a result, **i** is the number of calculated terms and **n** is the approached value of **π**.

following part is my code:

```
def GL(n):
    a, pi, flag = 1, 0, True
    while a <= (n*2-1):
        if flag:
            pi += (4/a)
        else:
            pi -= (4/a)
        flag = not flag
        a += 2
    return pi


def MvS(n):
    flag, a, parentheses, i = True, 3, 1, 1
    while a <= (n*2-1):
        if flag:
            parentheses -= (1/(a*3**i))
        else:
            parentheses += (1/(a*3**i))
        i += 1
        a += 2
        flag = not flag
    return math.sqrt(12)*parentheses


def approach_pi(n):
    counter_GL, counter_MvS, i = 0, 0, 2
    while 10**(-n-1) > GL(i-1) - GL(i) > (-10**(-n-1)):
        counter_GL += 1
        i += 1
    i = 2
    while 10**(-n-1) > MvS(i-1) - MvS(i) > (-10**(-n-1)):
        counter_MvS += 1
        i += 1

    return counter_GL, counter_MvS, GL(i)


x = int(input("give n : "))
print(approach_pi(x))
```

I know the last function is not at all correct but I'm out of ideas. Could someone explain me the proper reasoning for this problem?

Some example solutions are:
approach_pi(3): (10, 3.14159051093808)
approach_pi(2): (8, 3.141568715941784)
approach_pi(6): (16, 3.1415926517339976)

Comment: Please clarify the problem and be more specific than not being correct. How do you know that it's not correct? What do you expect instead? Can you remove all the code not being necessary for the problem? What searches have you performed to solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The image you posted may be subject to copyright, are you allowed to post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This becomes a lot more efficient if you build your functions as generators, so you don't have to rerun the entire sequence every time.

Computing closeness is just a matter of `if abs(this - lastthis) < epsilon`.

This seems to work, and it shows how bad the Gregory-Leibniz method is:

```
import math

def GL():
    a, pi, flag = 1, 0, True
    while True:
        if flag:
            pi += (4/a)
        else:
            pi -= (4/a)
        flag = not flag
        a += 2
        yield pi

def MvS():
    flag, a, parentheses, i = True, 3, 1, 1
    yield 3
    while True:
        if flag:
            parentheses -= (1/(a*3**i))
        else:
            parentheses += (1/(a*3**i))
        i += 1
        a += 2
        flag = not flag
        yield math.sqrt(12)*parentheses


def approach_pi(n):
    epsilon = 10**(-n)
    oldg = 0
    oldm = 0
    for i,gm in enumerate(zip(GL(), MvS())):
        g,m = gm
        print(i,g,m)
        if abs(g-oldg) < epsilon:
            print( "GL converges at step", i )
            return i+1,g
        if abs(m-oldm) < epsilon:
            print( "MvS converges at step", i )
            return i+1,m
        oldg,oldm = g,m


approach_pi(6)
```

You can eliminate the "flags" by unrolling the loops:

```
import math

def GL():
    a, pi = 1, 0
    while True:
        pi += (4/a)
        a += 2
        yield pi
        pi -= (4/a)
        a += 2
        yield pi

def MvS():
    parentheses, a, denom = 1, 3, 3
    yield 3
    while True:
        parentheses -= (1/(a*denom))
        a += 2
        denom *= -3
        yield math.sqrt(12)*parentheses


def approach_pi(n):
    epsilon = 10**(-n)
    oldg = 0
    oldm = 0
    for i,gm in enumerate(zip(GL(), MvS())):
        g,m = gm
        print(i,g,m)
        if abs(g-oldg) < epsilon:
            print( "GL converges at step", i )
            return i+1,g
        if abs(m-oldm) < epsilon:
            print( "MvS converges at step", i )
            return i+1,m
        oldg,oldm = g,m


approach_pi(6)
```

Comment: Good answer! You only need to return the tuple required.

Comment: They must be counting differently.  The value you show as "10" is number 8, counting from 0.  Are they treating the 3 as the first result?  That's easy to compensate for, and you should have been able to figure it out.

Comment: Did you see I adjusted the code so it matches your numbers?  I just included "3" as the first result, and started counting with 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you very much. I'm currently trying to fully understand your choices for certain parts of the code like the use of 'yield' over 'return' and a 'while true'? loop.
Thanks again for your time and effort

Comment: I mentioned that the code becomes much more efficient with generators,  That's what "yield" does.  It lets the function return a bunch of things, one at a time.  This is the way the `range` function is implemented.  Without that, you have to regenerate the whole sequence from scratch every time you call each function.